# Self join when two tables are joining

Tags: sql, self-join

I have 2 table with parent foreign key relationship
Table1 - (id1, pIntID, fid) id1-primary key, fid foreign key
Table2 - (fid, value) fid primary key

values will be something like this
table1

```
id1, pIntID, fid
1    IR1     AC
2    IR1     RJ
3    IR2     AC
4    IR2     AC
```

table2

```
fid, value
AC   accept
RJ   reject
```

I have to select those pIntID from table one whose tablle2.value = Accept but not Reject. I am able to do it using subquery but that will perform badly on huge data, Is there an optimal way to do it?

this is the working query:

```
select t1.pIntid
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.fid = t2.fid
where t2.value = 'accept' and
      t1.pIntid not in (select tx1.pintid
                        from table1 tx1 join
                             table2.tx2
                             on tx1.fid = tx2.fid
                        where tx2.value = 'reject'
                       )
```

Comment: First of all, in general, performance is not determined by which method you use to perform the operation. In all vendors databases, the underlying Query processors will optimize the query using more or less the same basic join algorithms, regardless of how you structure the SQL. So first, for clarity and maintainability, you should write the SQL so that it represents the functional purpose you intend, and then only investigate alternative approaches when a performance problem becomes apparent.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little twisted since it has a constraint in where clause, but I believe would work:

```
select t1.pintid
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.fid = t2.fid
where t2.value in ('accept', 'reject')
group by t1.pintid
having count(distinct t2.value) = 1
   and t2.value = 'accept'
```

Another solution (cleaner I guess) would be using `NOT EXISTS` to exclude those `pintid` that contain `accept` but also `reject` state:

```
select t1.pintid
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.fid = t2.fid
where t2.value = 'accept'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from table1 t1x
    join table2 t2x on t1x.fid = t2x.fid
    where t2x.value = 'reject'
      and t1.pintid = t1x.pintid
    )
group by t1.pintid
```

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, you could use an anti-join pattern.

```
 SELECT t1.pIntid
   FROM table1 t1
   JOIN table2 t2
     ON t2.fid   = t1.fid
    AND t2.value = 'accept'
   LEFT
   JOIN table2 tx2
     ON tx2.fid   = t1.fid
    AND tx2.value = 'reject'
  WHERE tx2.fid IS NULL
```

The anti-join pattern is an outer join, with a condition in the WHERE clause that excludes rows that found a match.

For optimal performance, we want appropriate covering index available on table2. With `fid` and `value` as the leading columns in the index.

If there are multiple rows in table2 with value='accept' for the same fid, then the join operation will produce "duplicate" rows.